# Foam roller and massage ball

Tags: recovery, muscle-recovery, foam-rolling

I want to buy a foam roller and massage ball for self massage and myofascial release. What are things/features to look out for when buying these? Also, is it worth to invest in a known brand or do the cheap ones do the trick as well?

Answer (score -2):

You may want to select the type depending on your purpose such as Grid, For Physical Therapy, Half Roller, Stick, and Vibrating. Get 24 inch foam roller for your arms/legs and 36 inch for your back.

Comment: Could you provide some detail on why the different sizes for arms/legs and back?

Comment: Additionally, if you could relate each of the different types you listed to their specific purpose it would make this a better answer.